# Script with Crontab runs VLC Video Without Sound

Tags: shell-script, cron, audio, environment-variables, vlc

I have set up a testing script to play videos on `VLC-3.0.12` *(Manjaro)* using `crontab` *(cronie-1.5.7)*. The file in question looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
## YES, I'M RICKROLLING MYSELF FOR TESTING

[[ "$HOME" != "/home/drjeff16" ]] && exit 1
[[ -n "$(pgrep vlc)" ]] && exit 1

# SINCE CRON DOES NOT SET THE EXISTING X11 ENV VARS, SET THE DISPLAY MANUALLY
DISPLAY=:0.0

if [[ "$isCron" == "0" ]] ; then                                # IF RUNNING FROM REGULAR TERMINAL ENVIRONMENT
  echo '[[ -n "$(pgrep vlc)" ]] && killall vlc' | /usr/bin/at now + 5 minutes
  nhp vlc "$HOME"/Videos/Music/Never-Gonna-Give-You-Up.mp4      # 'nhp' IS 'nohup <command> &!' AS AN EXPORTED
                                                                # FUNCTION TO AVOID APPS HIJACKING MY TERMINAL
  exit 0
elif [[ "$isCron" == "1" ]] ; then                              # ELSE IF RUNNING FROM CRONTAB ($isCron IS 1 ON CRON ENV)
  echo '[[ -n "$(pgrep vlc)" ]] && killall vlc' | /usr/bin/at now + 5 minutes
  vlc "$HOME"/Videos/Music/Never-Gonna-Give-You-Up.mp4
  exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

Executing this script from my normal environment does not cause any issues. However, when running it from `crontab`, *VLC does run and display video, but no audio comes out anywhere*.

While reading the manual entry for VLC `man vlc`, I came across the `$OSSAUDIO_DEV` variable in the `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` section:

```
.
.
OSSAUDIO_DEV
              The default audio output device, used by the OSSv4 output plugin.
.
.
```

My question is whether I need to set the `$OSSAUDIO_DEV` variable manually on my `crontab` environment, or if another variable that has to do with `ALSA`, `Pulseaudio`, or my `dbus` session has to be declared manually in my *crontab* file:

```bsh
# *    *    *   *    *  Command_to_execute
# |    |    |    |   |       
# |    |    |    |    Day of the Week ( 0 - 6 ) ( Sunday = 0 )
# |    |    |    |
# |    |    |    Month ( 1 - 12 )
# |    |    |
# |    |    Day of Month ( 1 - 31 )
# |    |
# |    Hour ( 0 - 23 )
# |
# Min ( 0 - 59 )

SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/home/drjeff16
DISPLAY=:0.0
.
.
.
EDITOR="$(cat $HOME/.editor)"
isCron=1
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why don't you just try? I would definitely look for a missing environment variable; cron's environment is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my boilerplate `cron` answer, I hope some of it helps.

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with7 `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define XDG. For example:

```
* * * * * XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) /path/to/script
```

Sound started working for me. Do not forget to edit job timing (* * * * *) so it does not run every minute.